# "Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?" when trying to use \tkzDefPoint

Tags: tkz-euclide

I'm trying to draw some points in a for loop, but I keep getting this error "Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?".

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=latex,<->}}
\tikzset{yaxe style/.style ={>=latex,<->}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-16.5, xmax=16, ymin=-8.5, ymax=8, xstep=4, ystep=4]
\tkzAxeXY
\foreach \i in {0,...,11} {
    \tkzDefPoint(\i*pi/6:8){P_(\i+1)}
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
    \tkzDrawPoint[color=blue](P_\i)
}
\tkzDrawPoint[color=blue](12)
\foreach \i in {6,...,11} {
    \tkzDrawPoint[color=red](P_\i)
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Full error message:

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 }
```

Comment: Please provide the missing parts betwwen \documentclass and \end{document}, so we can copy, compile and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the only thing needed here was `tkz-fct`, but in general please do as MS-SPO said in the comment, and add complete, minimal examples that can be tested without any modification.

---

There are a couple of issues. First of all, the parentheses around the subscript in `\tkzDefPoint(\i*pi/6:8){P_(\i+1)}`. At the end, `\tkzDefPoint{<coord>}(<name>)` does something like `\coordinate (<name>) at (<coord>);`, so when your `<name` contains parentheses, the parser is confused. Later in your code you don't use those parentheses though, so seems like you don't want them anyway?

Second, there is no parsing of mathematical expressions in the label, so with `P_(\i+1)` that ends up with e.g. `\coordinate (P_(0+1)) at ...`, not `\coordinate (P_1) at ...` which I think you actually want. In this case you can use `\foreach [count=\j from 1] ...` and `P_\j` as the coordinate name.

Thirdly, you need to use degrees, not radians, so replace `pi` with `180`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-16.5, xmax=16, ymin=-8.5, ymax=8, xstep=4, ystep=4]
\tkzAxeXY
\foreach [count=\j from 1] \i in {0,...,11} {
    \tkzDefPoint(\i*180/6:8){P_\j}
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
    \tkzDrawPoint[color=blue](P_\i)
}

\foreach \i in {6,...,11} {
    \tkzDrawPoint[color=red](P_\i)
}

\tkzDrawPoint[color=black](P_12)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much